# knockoutjs: computed observables in cascaded arrays (complex viewmodel) and the this-pointer

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, viewmodel

EDIT:
as suggested I refactored my viewmodel:
- using constructor functions
- using sub-"things"

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/drchef/hSMkc/1/

now, the computed is working ;) thx

but is still have one question left:
If i change the food values, the values don't get back in the model.
The metadata is working find but the food values not. (and so the total doesn't get updated)

P.S.: sry, i am new to SO ... should i start a new question?

===========================================================

first of all, I post my viewmodel ;)

```
var vm = function() {

var self = this;    

this.activeRow = ko.observable(0);
this.user = 'hungry guy';

this.foods = ['pizza', 'burger', 'chilli'];
this.meetings = [
    {year: 2014, types: [{type: "until now", hidden: false}, {type: "forecast", hidden: false}]},
    {year: 2015, types: [{type: "forecast", hidden: false}]}
];

this.lines = ko.observableArray([
    {   id: 1,
        meta: ko.observable(
            {   shop: ko.observable('foodstore'),
                tel: ko.observable('123 456'),
                url: ko.observable('foodstore24.com')
            }),
        meetingValues: ko.observableArray([
            {   productValues: ko.observableArray([
                    {productValue: ko.observable(1)},
                    {productValue: ko.observable(0)},
                    {productValue: ko.observable(1)}]),
                total: ko.computed(function() {
                    //console.log(this.lines) -> expected: array output -> actual: undefined
                    //console.log(this.lines()) -> expected: array output -> actual: error, this.lines() ist not a function
                    //console.log(this) -> expected: this == self -> actual: this == self
                    return 0;
                }, this)
            },
            {   productValues: ko.observableArray([
                    {productValue: ko.observable(3)},
                    {productValue: ko.observable(2)},
                    {productValue: ko.observable(5)}]),
                total: ko.computed(function() {
                    return 0;
                })
            },
            {   productValues: ko.observableArray([
                    {productValue: ko.observable(2)},
                    {productValue: ko.observable(2)},
                    {productValue: ko.observable(3)}]),
                total: ko.computed(function() {
                    return 0;
                })
            }
            ])
    }
]);

};
```

ok, I have to say some words to this model.

this is my complex knockoutjs model. I apply it with:

```
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

this model holds 1 "line". this.lines is a array and could hold much more but for this question this one line is enought.

this.foods and this.meetings are headings for the resulting table. The table looks like this:

```
| 2014                                                              | 2015
| until now                       | forecast                        | forecast
| pizza | burger | chilli | total | pizza | burger | chilli | total | pizza | burger | chilli | total |
|     1 |      0 |      1 |     0 |     3 |      2 |      5 |     0 |     2 |      2 |      3 |     0 |
```

It is a litte bit hard to explain but with the table and the vm, i think it is understandable ;)

this.user/foods/meetings are not observable, because they neven change on the client side.

As you can see in the vm, there a comments with my problem.
In the "total"-column I want sum of the three foods. (return pizza + burger + chilli)
But this is not working, because "this" is not working. I can't get access to the values.

Can somebody explain the problem to me?
Is this viewmodel good practise?

I'm using knockout.js.3.1.0.

thx for your answers
gruß

P.S.: please ask me, if somebody doesn't understand the problem ;)

Comment: You should define subobjects (meta, meetingvalues, etc), this is kind of messy

Comment: can you make fiddle so its easy to explain and debug+

Comment: @GoTo ok ;) i'll do this...that I'll come back an edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a plain JS object for a view model. It's considerably hard to have computeds and manage `this` correctly if you do so. I suggest using constructor functions for your sub View Models too, which will make those (and many other) problems and hard situations go away. The [KO documentation has some info](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#managing-this) on this. That may also clarify what the `self=this` thing is for (you have it in your code for your main VM, but don't use it).

If you have/want to stick with the plain JS object, then I'd suggest adding the computeds after creating the main observables. Something like this:

```
this.lines = ko.observableArray([
    {   id: 1,
        meta: ko.observable(
            {   shop: ko.observable('foodstore'),
                tel: ko.observable('123 456'),
                url: ko.observable('foodstore24.com')
            }),
        meetingValues: ko.observableArray([
            {   productValues: ko.observableArray([
                    {productValue: ko.observable(1)},
                    {productValue: ko.observable(0)},
                    {productValue: ko.observable(1)}])
            }
            //etc
            ])
    }
]);

// See note, below code
this.lines()[0].meetingValues()[0].total = ko.computed(function() {
    //console.log(this.lines) -> expected: array output -> actual: undefined
    //console.log(this.lines()) -> expected: array output -> actual: error, this.lines() ist not a function
    //console.log(this) -> expected: this == self -> actual: this == self
    return 0;
}, this.lines()[0].meetingValues()[0]);
```

Note: the example above sets the `total` for only one `meetingValues`, you'd have to add the computed to all of them using loops. This is again one of the reasons I'd suggest using constructor functions for View Models as it makes managing `this` and computeds in general much easier.

Comment: thx, so if I define "subobjects" makes everthing "easier"? No, i don't want to stick with the plain JS object if this sucks. I really don't use the "self" ... i only included it to understand the third comment inside the vm. For me it seems "this" is correct but there is no ".lines" inside the "this". this/self.user inside the computed is working without problems. So just in short: I have to port this to a constructor function and also to make "sub" custroctor functions and put them inside the array? thx...i'll give this a try ;)